# How do I get full details of each person when joining tables

Tags: mysql, join

I know this has to have a simple solution and I am not seeing it.

I have a table, `person`, which contains all information about each person such as first name, last name, age, address.

I have a second table called `consumer_client` which contains a row containing person id for each consumer and client like this:

```
id | consumer_person_id | client_person_id
```

What I want is to fetch both full names when I join `person` to `client_consumer` like this:

```
id | Joe Mama | Mike Smith
```

I cannot seem to get that with a simple JOIN syntax like

```
SELECT * FROM person JOIN client_consumer WHERE person.person_id = cc.person_id
```

as it always returns just the `consumer_person_id` and `client_person_id` along with other information in person. I want it replaced with the full name instead of `person_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking at this the wrong way around. You should be selecting from the client_consumer table and joining to the person table. This way the query is easily read and understood.

```
SELECT
    cc.id,
    consumer.full_name as consumer_full_name,
    client.full_name as client_full_name
FROM client_consumer cc
JOIN person consumer ON
    consumer.person_id = cc.consumer_person_id
JOIN person client ON
    client.person_id = cc.client_person_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to look at it starting from your example.

First we set up the example:

```
-- Setup Data
CREATE TABLE person (
       person_id int IDENTITY(1,1)
      ,first_name varchar(25)
      ,last_name Varchar(25));


CREATE TABLE consumer_client (
       id int IDENTITY(1,1)
      ,consumer_person_id Int
      ,client_person_id Int);

INSERT INTO dbo.person
        (first_name, last_name)
VALUES  ('John', 'Smith')
        ,('Bob','Jones')

INSERT INTO dbo.consumer_client
        (consumer_person_id, client_person_id)
VALUES  (1,2)
```

Now we select the data joining to the Person table a second time for the Client Name:

```
-- Select Data

SELECT p1.person_id AS id, p1.first_name + ' ' + p1.last_name AS [Consumer Name], 
       p2.first_name + ' ' + p2.last_name AS [Client Name]
FROM person p1
JOIN consumer_client cc ON p1.person_id = cc.consumer_person_id
JOIN person p2 ON p2.person_id = cc.client_person_id
```

Results:

```
id Consumer Name  Client Name
-- -------------  -----------
 1 John Smith     Bob Jones
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't correctly join the two tables. And you also didn't identify what "cc" was.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM person 
JOIN client_consumer cc ON person.person_id = cc.person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to return only certain results and not the id. I made some modifications and added the pertinent columns. However, you may have an issue as the columns you stated aren't there and there are 2 id columns. We need to know which you want to join on or if you need to join on both. Here is the concatenation that you require:

```
SELECT  (p.firstname +' '+ p.lastname) AS fullname 
FROM client_consumer cc 
JOIN person ON p.person_id = cc.consumer_person_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on formatting the select part. I will be start using that!

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking to do is pretty straightforward, and I see some good answers already, but here is the simplest version. You need to join the consumer_client table twice to the person table. So

```
SELECT p1.*, p2.*
FROM consumer_client cc
LEFT JOIN person p1 ON p1.person_id = cc.consumer_person_id
LEFT JOIN person p2 ON p2.person_id = cc.client_person_id
```

Although you'll probably want to alias the columns in the select statement, since you'll get duplicate columns with a straight up SELECT *